# How to get absolute path of a file located in the assets folder with react-native and expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

Simple question. I have an assets folder that is on my root directory, and I have some files there.

Example: assets/doc/wantedfile.pdf

I need to get the absolute path of this file, not the relative one. Probably is something like this: file:///data/expo/(...)/app/assets/doc/wantedfile.pdf

But the project is on expo so the solutions that I found here to this problem for Android and IOS didn't work. The solution must work with expo.

I can't use RNFetchBlob because it needs to link (don't work on expo)

Can't detach of expo because the project is very big and it will require a lot of work.

Don't know if RNFS works with expo, didn't tested yet, if it needs linking then doesn't work.

Any tips ?

I tried to use `FileSystem.documentDirectory` to get absolute path, but it gives me the path of an empty directory folder (i think that it is the directory folder of the emulator, not the application).

I need to get the abs path of the assets folder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `Asset` module

```
import { Asset } from 'expo';

...
async render() {
  const pdfURI = await Asset.fromModule(require('.assets/doc/wantedfile.pdf')).uri;
}
...
```

Check here for detail: https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/sdk/asset/#expoassetloadasyncmodules